# How to get Cumulative data from the same table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table

**table1**

```
eventid  entityid  eventdate
----------------------------------------
123       xyz      Jan-02-2019
541       xyz      Jan-02-2019
234       xyz      Jan-03-2019
432       xyz      Jan-04-2019
111       xyz      Jan-05-2019
124       xyz      Jan-06-2019
123       xyz      Jan-07-2019
234       xyz      Jan-08-2019
432       xyz      Jan-09-2019
111       xyz      Jan-12-2019
```

I want to show final result as

```
entityid  interval1  interval2 
------------------------------
xyz         2            4
```

here intervals are in days.

Logic to calculate intervals are :

Ex - event 123 and 234 happens multiple time so date difference between each occurrence as shown below would be added finally into interval1.
Please note - its not necessary 234 would be always in a next row of 123. there could be other events in between.

Formula is

interval1 = datediff(day,eventdate of 123,eventdate of 234) + datediff(day,eventdate of 123,eventdate of 234) + and so on

Same for interval2 but for event 432 & 111.

```
entityid eventid1 eventid2  event_date_diff  
--------------------------------------------
xyz        123      234          1
xyz        123      234          1
xyz        432      111          1
xyz        432      111          3
```

The challenge here is to find out if event 123 has 234 event or not in upcoming rows (not necessarily in immediate next row) and if its there then find the date difference. If there are any other events between 123-234 then we need to ignore those in between events. Also if 123 appears twice then need latest eventdate for 123.

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: its sql server.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: I dont understand the logic.

Comment: What if there's another event between 123 and 234?

Comment: thats fine but I want to consider specific events only.

Comment: Hi Juan, formula is     interval1 = datediff(day,eventdate of 123,eventdate of 234) + datediff(day,eventdate of 123,eventdate of 234) + and so on

Comment: @Avinash Do you want to ignore the 123-234 intervals if there are other events in between or you want to ignore the events in between? What if you have 123 twice in a row without 234?

Comment: hello, I dont want to ignore 123-234 if there is any other event in between. I want to ignore events in between.  If 123 is twice then we need to tale latest eventdate for 123

Comment: And you query so far?

Comment: something like filter only 123 and 234, join with itself shifted by one row, then take datediff if it has 123 and 234, then summ them up. Are you sure you want to do it with a query?

Comment: I know it would be complex query. Just want to figure it out if its even possible to do with a query before I go for other solutions.

Comment: Currently I just have option to do with sql

Answer (score 3):

Let's go over this in terms of your requirements, and build up the necessary pieces.  This won't be approached in the order you stated them in, but in an order that makes them easier to understand.

> Also if 123 appears twice then need latest `eventdate` for 123.

This means we need to create a range bounds.  This is pretty easy:

```
NextOccurence AS (SELECT eventId, entityId, eventDate, 
                         LEAD(eventDate) OVER(PARTITION BY eventId, entityId ORDER BY eventDate) AS nextOccurenceDate
                  FROM Table1)
```

... this will give us every occurrence of an event, with the next one, if present (these *can* be limited to just your "source" events, but I'm not bothering with that here).

> The challenge here is to find out if event 123 has 234 event or not in upcoming rows (not necessarily in immediate next row) and if its there then find the date difference. If there are any other events between 123-234 then we need to ignore those in between events.

(and you previously mentioned it should be the *minimum* following date, if there were multiple following events).

For this we need to first map events:

```
EventMap AS (SELECT 123 AS original, 234 AS follow
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 432, 111)
```

... and use this to get the "next" following event in range, in what is partially a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query:

```
SELECT NextOccurence.entityId, NextOccurence.eventId, DATEDIFF(day, NextOccurence.eventDate, Table1.eventDate) AS diff
  FROM NextOccurence
  JOIN EventMap 
    ON EventMap.original = NextOccurence.eventId
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Table1.eventDate
               FROM Table1
               WHERE Table1.entityId = NextOccurence.entityId
                     AND Table1.eventId = EventMap.follow
                     AND Table1.eventDate >= NextOccurence.eventDate
                     AND (Table1.eventDate < NextOccurence.nextOccurenceDate OR NextOccurence.nextOccurenceDate IS NULL)
               ORDER BY Table1.eventDate) AS Table1
```

... at this point, we have something close to your intermediate results table:

```
| entityId | eventId | diff |
|----------|---------|------|
| xyz      | 123     | 1    |
| xyz      | 123     | 1    |
| xyz      | 432     | 1    |
| xyz      | 432     | 3    |
```

... and what follows afterwards would be a standard `PIVOT` query to aggregate the results.

The final query ends up looking like this:

```
WITH NextOccurence AS (SELECT eventId, entityId, eventDate, 
                       LEAD(eventDate) OVER(PARTITION BY eventId, entityId ORDER BY eventDate) AS nextOccurenceDate
                   FROM Table1),
     EventMap AS (SELECT 123 AS original, 234 AS follow
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 432, 111)
SELECT entityId, [123] AS '123-234', [432] AS '432-111'
FROM (SELECT NextOccurence.entityId, NextOccurence.eventId, DATEDIFF(day, NextOccurence.eventDate, Table1.eventDate) AS diff
      FROM NextOccurence
      JOIN EventMap 
        ON EventMap.original = NextOccurence.eventId
      CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Table1.eventDate
                   FROM Table1
                   WHERE Table1.entityId = NextOccurence.entityId
                         AND Table1.eventId = EventMap.follow
                         AND Table1.eventDate >= NextOccurence.eventDate
                         AND (Table1.eventDate < NextOccurence.nextOccurenceDate OR NextOccurence.nextOccurenceDate IS NULL)
                   ORDER BY Table1.eventDate) AS Table1) AS d
PIVOT (SUM(diff)
       FOR eventId IN ([123], [432])
       ) AS pvt
```

[<kbd>Fiddle example</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=a6968dbdeca9c9a60fb1aaf0a2143ff6)

...which generates the expected results:

```
| entityId | 123-234 | 432-111 |
|----------|---------|---------|
| xyz      | 2       | 4       |
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of the question, we are asked to provide occurrences of each eventid per date. However these are to be represented in columns rather than rows.

My approach to this problem is firstly to pivot the data within a cte and then to select the unique value from each column in to the cross apply operator of a query. There may be better ways of doing it but this made the most sense to me.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    EventId INT,
    EntityId NVARCHAR(3),
    EventDate DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO @T (EventId, EntityId, EventDate)
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
(123,       'xyz',      '2019-01-02'),
(234,       'xyz',      '2019-01-03'),
(432,       'xyz',      '2019-01-04'),
(111,       'xyz',      '2019-01-05'),
(124,       'xyz',      '2019-01-06'),
(123,       'xyz',      '2019-01-07'),
(234,       'xyz',      '2019-01-08'),
(432,       'xyz',      '2019-01-09'),
(111,       'xyz',      '2019-01-12')
) X (EVENTID, ENTITYID, EVENTDATE);

with cte as (
select EntityId, [123] as Interval1, [234] as Interval2, [432] as Interval3, [111] as 
Interval4, [124] as Interval5

from
(
select top 5 EntityId, EventId, min(eventdate) as ordering, count(distinct EventDate) 
as 
vol from @T
group by EntityId, EventId
order by ordering
) src
PIVOT
(
    max(vol)
    for EventId in ([123], [234], [432], [111], [124])
) as pvt)

select distinct EntityId, Interval1, Interval2, Interval3, Interval4, Interval5
from (select EntityId from cte) a
cross apply
(select Interval1 from cte where Interval1 is not null) b
cross apply
(select Interval2 from cte where Interval2 is not null) c
cross apply
(select Interval3 from cte where Interval3 is not null) d
cross apply
(select Interval4 from cte where Interval4 is not null) e
cross apply
(select Interval5 from cte where Interval5 is not null) f;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and conditional aggregation for this:

```
select sum(case when eventid = 123 and next_eventid = 234
                then datediff(day, eventdate, next_eventdate)
           end) as interval1,
       sum(case when eventid = 432 and next_eventid = 111
                then datediff(day, eventdate, next_eventdate)
           end) as interval2
from (select t.*,
             lead(eventid) over (partition by entityid order by eventdate) as next_eventid,
             lead(eventdate) over (partition by entityid order by eventdate) as next_eventdate
      from t
     ) t;
```

Probably the simplest way to handle intervening events is conditional cumulative arithemtic:

```
select sum(case when eventid = 123 and
                then datediff(day, eventdate, next_eventdate_234)
          end) as interval1,
       sum(case when eventid = 432 and
                then datediff(day, eventdate, next_eventdate_111)
          end) as interval2           
from (select t.*,
             min(case when eventid = 234 then eventdate end) over (order by eventdate desc) as next_eventdate_234,
             min(case when eventid = 111 then eventdate end) over (order by eventdate desc) as next_eventdate_111
      from t
      where eventid in (123, 234)
     ) t
where eventid in (123, 432);
```

Comment: `LEAD` is only going to work if the immediate next event is the desired "followup".  My read of the situation is that that's _not_ a guarantee.

Comment: @Avinash . . . It works for the data you have posted.  And the question is phrased in such a way ("in sequence") that it suggests that this is always true.

Comment: Sorry. It would in sequence means 123 would always occur before 234 but there is no guaranty that these both event 234 would be always in next row for 123. There could be some other events in between.

Comment: @Avinash . . . The same ideas can be used, but the logic needs to be tweaked.

Comment: Note that this fails one of the other conditions - if there's multiple `123` events before any `234` events, the difference will appear twice.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . At this point, the OP has changed the question so many times that it is not worth trying to answer.

Comment: I am sorry Gordon. I had to change the question to make it more clear. I tried your tweaked solution and it seems to be working. I am just checking some scenarios and if every thing is good will accept your answer.

Comment: @Avinash . . . As pointed out, it will not work if you have multiple values of the same values in a row.  It would have been better to ask a new question.